# limit access to webpage by login with a list of generated unique ids

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, fraud-prevention

I am building a voting kiosk (iPad that is present in the exhibition space) that will be used to vote for projects taking part in an exhibition in a museum. I am using Typeform (http://www.typeform.com/) to generate the voting form. That's all working perfect. The only issue is that I need to limit the voting to one vote per person. I thought that asking for an email address in the beginning of the form would do the trick, but that's far from perfect. People have more than one address, and since there is no real way of validating the address, also things like something@gmail.com will fool the system. So I thought to add a login page before the form. Visitors will get a unique code when buying the ticket to the exhibition and with this code they can log in once to go through the voting process. The fact that all votes come from the same IP/source rules out any IP based solutions.
How can I go about building this login page? I am quite comfortable with PHP and JavaScript, but I need a start here on coding a login form that will accept only codes from a generated list of unique codes (and generating this list as well).
If you a better idea altogether, I'm open for suggestions!
Thanks, Ehud.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MySQL DB. You could collect the IP's (One Account per IP), also you can set a User ID with is unique. So, if someone votes, the DB collects an requests If the user already set a vote.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It might not be completely clear from my description, but the voting kiosk is a (iPad) station that is present in the exhibition space, so all voting will be done from the same IP.